# unable to see variable

Tags: c#, variables, visibility

stupid question,but still. I have some variable, let it be `MyVariable`, which gets its value in one of the methods in code-behind, in `MouseClick`, for example, but then value of `MyVariable`is used in a method in another class(I'm using different Patterns). Of course, in this class `MyVariable` is invisible, but what is better to do?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Hero Hero1 = new Hero();
    Notify newNotify = new Notify();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Collections coll = new Collections();
    }
    private void weapons_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Hero1.Attack = ((Weapon) listweapons.SelectedItem)._attack;
        newNotify.ThrowHero().Attack  = Hero1.Attack;
        newNotify.Dropped += Show_Message;
        newNotify.DroppedEquipment();

        TextBox2.Text = newNotify.ThrowHero().Description;//this gets its value from attack
    }
    public void Show_Message()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(newNotify.ThrowHero().Description =
             "Защита:" + newNotify.ThrowHero().Protection + "атака:" + newNotify.ThrowHero().Attack);
    }
}
```

and then i have another method in another class

```
public class SavingInWord : IWordSaving
{
    public void ExportToWord()
    {
        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = false;
        Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
        doc.Select();
        wordApp.Selection.TypeText("Description:" + newNotify.ThrowHero().Description); //newNotify.ThrowHero().Description) can't be seen here, but i need to have the value here which i got from weapons_DragLeave method
        doc.SaveAs(@"D:...doc");
        wordApp.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

in another class:

```
public class Notify
{
    Hero hero1 = new Hero();
    public Hero ThrowHero()
    {
        return hero1;
    }
    public delegate void MyEventhandler();

    public event MyEventhandler Dropped;

    public void DroppedEquipment()
    {
        if (Dropped != null)
            Dropped();
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll be better  to ask a correct question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Make `MyVariable` a global public variable

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @J3soon global public variables are a horrible practice, and as such, they do not even exist in C#

Comment: Which variable is `MyVariable`?

Comment: @user2946329 i've updated my question

Comment: I still can't tell which variable is the invisible one.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Comment: @AustinWBryan it is newNotify.ThrowHero().Description) in method ExportToWord, because it is not in public partial class MainWindow : Window

Comment: @AustinWBryan I mean a global public variable in a namespace. And the reason i said that is because his question is unclear then.

Comment: my variable get its value in a method in public partial class MainWindow : Window. so in another class this variable doesn't exist if i try to use it

Comment: #J3soon, C# can't declare any variables in namespaces, I believe it can only declare class in namespaces. While this is limiting, you can create a `static class Globals` at the root most namespace to achieve this affect.

Comment: @AustinWBryan but i can't do such thing namespace MyHeroEditor
{ Notify newNotify = new Notify();

    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {...
it is underlined with red and says "} expected"

Comment: @AustinWBryan i'll try to creare static globals

Comment: @AustinWBryan thak you so much, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root-most `namespace`

```
public static class Globals
{
    Notify newNotify = new Notify();
}
```

Then you'll be able to access it from where ever.